# Properly venting washing machine drain

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I am trying to figure out how to properly vent a new washing machine drain line that will tie into an existing drain; however, the existing drain is 10.5' away from the washing machine drain.

Sources seem to indicate this is either fine, or needs to have a vent within 5' or 8' of the washing machine p-trap. The first figure shows the setup.

Is this setup ok as is, b/c the existing vent is above the water line of the washing machine p-trap? (See https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o).

Or do I need to add in a vent for the washing machine? If so, can I connect it to the existing vent to keep from having to run a second vent line. See the second figure.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Proposed drain]
[image: Proposed drain w/possible vent connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like your second drawing should *work*, though it's not technically *correct* (nor is the first) by the code I'm under (IPC, with some local amendments,) which requires that all vents run at least 45° upward (which they define as "vertical") until they are **6" above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served.**

So a *correct* version would be with both vents running upward until that level, and then they can turn horizontal (actually 2% slope to drain), and they can be joined to the single vertical vent (assuming it's of adequate size, but that's likely unless it's tiny, as a dry vent.)

Alternatively, I think you could use 3" pipe for the washer drain (but I haven't double-checked that.) However, the original vent would still be wrong, if it's as drawn.

Comment: Thank you! Would I be better off maintaining the new vent line at a 45° until it meets the existing vertical vent? I cannot modify the existing horizontal vent b/c of a window. 

For second part - does a 3" drain pipe mean I don't need a vent?

Comment: Yes, that would be better. You always need a vent. The 3" line might, depending on your applicable code, allow you to use the existing non-compliant vent. I'd consider 2" line and the 45 to the existing pipe (or straight up and then over at the correct level to it - whichever is easier) preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much!